# C# Thread Safe Way to get Label Text in Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

Could someone give me some ideas on the proper "Thread Safe" way to get Label Text from a Form?  I am currently getting a CrossThreadingMessaging exception.  I know I should be using a delegate, but I am having issues getting this to work correctly.  Can someone give me an example?  I have a label in my main form that I want to get the text from.  I have to make the call from another class.  Any guidance here would be much appreciated.

Rob

Here is my scenario:

I have to create an application that will grab the weight from a USB scale and deliver this wait back to a legacy system via a DDE call.  The legacy system makes a DDE call to my executable to get the weight via a emulator program.  I am trying to mimic the old VB 5 application in a C# application.  Believe me there are many other ways I would like to do this, but I was told to do it this way by management.  I have captured the weight in the label text, but now I have to get the weight from the label on the main form and return it when the DDE OnRequest method is executed.  This is where I am getting the CrossThreading exception.  The OnRequest is in a class outside of the main form class of course.

Comment: Here you go:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: @code4life this is for windows forms...

Comment: Additionally, I am using .NET 4.0 Framework...

Comment: Justin pointed out the right answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/661662/1174942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the property getter for a Label's Text property can be done from a thread without invoking the IllegalOperationException you'd normally get.  That's an implementation detail, the value of the Text property is cached in an internal string.  For example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var t = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(label1.Text));
        t.Start();
    }
```

No exception.  But setting the Text property will certainly invoke the hammer.  This doesn't otherwise make it a good idea to use this kind of code.  Use threads to perform non-UI related work, give them what they need when you start them.  And favor the BackgroundWorker class, it is very handy to give thread-safe progress updates and a thread-safe result.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Please take a look at my updated scenario, and any comments or suggestions would be great.